# retrive function in linked list python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

Im new into linked list in python. Here im doing find function and get the parameter index and to retrieve the item on that index. It worked well for the first two index but when it comes to index three
it still return me the same item on index two.

```
class Link:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self,element,_next):
            self.element = element
            self._next = _next

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def push(self, element):
        self.head = self.Node(element,self.head)
        self.size += 1

    def find(self,index):
        if self.isempty():
            raise IsEmptyError("This stack is empty")
        self.cur = self.head
        for x in range(index-1):
            self.cur = self.head._next
        return self.cur

    def retrive(self,index):
        self.curd = self.find(index)
        self.item = self.curd.element
        return self.item

from linkedlist import IsEmptyError
from linkedlist import Link

s = Link()
s.push("one")
s.push("two")
s.push("three")
get1 = s.retrive(1)
get2 = s.retrive(2)
get3 = s.retrive(3)
print(get1,get2,get3)
```

output = three two two

Process finished with exit code 0

It will supposed to get the output three two one. Is there any wrong in my code? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `find()` function:

```
    def find(self,index):
        if self.isempty():
            raise IsEmptyError("This stack is empty")
        self.cur = self.head
        for x in range(index-1):
            self.cur = self.head._next
        return self.cur
```

Specifically it's the for loop. For each iteration of the loop, you are **continuously only calling the node next to the head**, because you did `self.cur = self.head._next`. So, **you aren't actually iterating over the list**. The simple fix is to change it to `self.cur = self.curr._next` which actually *progresses to the next item in the linked list*.

By the way, it's better practice to have i as your iterator in a for loop rather than x, which would look like `for i in range(index - 1)`.

Comment: thank you so much! finally fixed it. Appreciate it!